# Change Facebook's language programmatically IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-signin

This is the thing: I have a button for changing the current language of my app. That works perfectly, but, my social buttons (such as Google and Facebook) don't change the language (`GIDSignInButton, FBSDKLoginButton`). I guess they get the current language of my device at the AppDelegate, but, I don't want to mess around rebooting the app or with the app delegate.

Any recommendation? Can I restart the facebook system programmatically in order to get the language again?

This is my setLanguage method:

```
+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
{
    //if language not supported we default to spanish
    if (language == nil || ![SMLocalizedString isLanguageSupported:language]){
        //defaults to spanish
        language = @"es";
    }

    //Sotres new language setting in user preferences

    [SMLocalizedString updateCurrentLanguage:language];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle], [BundleEx class]);
    });



    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:language, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    id value = language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil;
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &kBundleKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Show an alert `"Changing language needs restart. Are you sure you want to change the language?"` and on clicking of `Yes` button just restart the app with animation (Its possible).

Comment: What do you mean about 'just restart the app with animation (it's possible)' ? Is there a method to restart my app therefore, restart my facebook and google current language?

Comment: Yes you can restart (exit) the app with animation. I guess after changing the language restart the app can work for you. I'm not sure.